# How to find the 2 smallest integers that is divisible by 40131 and 41405

Tags: number-theory, homework, factorization

I'm trying to find the two smallest integers that is divisible by 40131 and 41405, i.e 40131|a, 41405|a, 40131|b and 41405|b. There is a hint within the question that says you can use FactorInteger[] but I'm not sure how I am supposed to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LCM (least common multiple). But it may be more instructive to see the prime factors. Look at:

```
FactorInteger[40131]
```

{{3, 2}, {7, 3}, {13, 1}}

```
FactorInteger[41405]
```

{{5, 1}, {7, 2}, {13, 2}}

So the smallest common multiple must have 2 times 3, one 5, three times 7, e.t.c
3 3 5 7 7 7 13 13

This gives: 2608515, the same result as LCM gives.

Comment: I think phrasing it as "m times n" may confuse some people into thinking you're talking about multiplication instead of counting prime factors.

Answer (score 3):

There are relation between `GCD` and `LCM` for two integers,that is

```
LCM[m, n]*GCD[m,n] === m*n
( * True *)
```

so we can use variety methods to get least common multiple and then all the common multiple.

```
m = 40131;
n = 41405;
m*n/GCD[m, n]
LCM[m, n]
```

Answer (score 2):

A closely related approach:

```
GCD[40131,41405]
```

(* 637 *)

so we search for the smallest $a$ and $b$ such that $a \cdot 63 \cdot 637 = b \cdot 65 \cdot 637$ or $a \cdot 63 = b \cdot 65$.

Because $63$ and $65$ are relatively prime, we read immediately that $a = 65$ and $b = 63$.  That gives you the smallest.

For the next-larger:  $2a$ and $2b$.

The rest follows trivially.

Comment: Umm... why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

brute force

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, ! (Mod[#, 40131] == 0 && Mod[#, 41405] == 0) &]
```

> 2608515

Answer (score 0):

Let us calculate the common integer factors of both integers
Union@Flatten@{(FactorInteger@40131)[[All,
1]], (FactorInteger@41405)[[All, 1]]}

(* 3, 5, 7, 13 *)

Prepare a new integer factor list:

```
lst = Partition[Riffle[%17, {0, 0, 0, 0}], 2]
lst1 = Join[FactorInteger@40131, FactorInteger@41405]

Table[If[lst[[i, 1]] == lst1[[j, 1]], 
  lst[[i, 2]] = Max[lst[[i, 2]], lst1[[j, 2]]], Nothing], {j, 1, 
  Length[lst1]}, {i, 1, Length[lst]}]

lst
```

(* {{3, 2}, {5, 1}, {7, 3}, {13, 2}} *)

Calculate the smallest integer that is divisible by both integers:

```
Times @@ Apply[Power, lst, {1}]
```

(* 2608515 *)

```
{2608515/40131,2608515/41405}
```

(* {65,63} *)

Since all the integer factors are prime the next integer larger than that has to contain all of them. So two times the given number does the deal.